# Numbering in a newtheorem environment using a pre-part

Tags: numbering

In a newtheorem environment I'd like to have two digits stable in the beginning of the counter.

For example

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
.
.
.
\begin{document}
\begin{example}[15]
...
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

The result should be:
**Example 15[example counter]**

Comment: If I understand, you can try this `\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{[15]or what you mean\thesection.\arabic{example}}` don't use `\begin{example}[15]` try with `\begin{example}`

Comment: I'd like to change this "pre"-number across the document. For example in some cases i'd like to be 15, while in other cases of example it should be 14 or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{example}{Example\Mytwodigits}[section]
\newcommand{\Mytwodigits}{}
\newcommand{\mytwodigits}[1]{\renewcommand{\Mytwodigits}{\space#1}}

\begin{document}
\mytwodigits{[15]}
\begin{example}
...
\end{example}
...

\mytwodigits{[14]}
\begin{example}
...
\end{example}
\end{document}
```